# VBA Code to Parse XML Pictures from Ebay API

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the three image URLS from this XML.

I can get the first image but struggle to find a solution to loop through and get all the image URLs

```xml
<PictureDetails>
    <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
    <PhotoDisplay>PicturePack</PhotoDisplay>
        <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/0zYAAOSwkARdzcXA/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>
       <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/Dq4AAOSwa-hdxedG/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005007</PictureURL>   
       <PictureURL>https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/ODAwWDgwMA==/z/xtYAAOSwwMxdxedH/$_57.JPG?set_id=8800005
007</PictureURL>
</PictureDetails>
```

```vb
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
     objXML.LoadXML (objHTTP.ResponseText)
 

     Dim xItemList As IXMLDOMNodeList
     Set xItemList = objXML.SelectNodes("//PictureDetails")

     Dim xItem As IXMLDOMNode


     For Each xItem In xItemList
     
        eBayImgURL = xItem.SelectNodes("//PictureURL").Item(0).Text
        Debug.Print "Image URL"
        Debug.Print eBayImgURL
        
     Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood how XPATH works:

- `xItemList` is just the one root node, at least if the small sample you have shared is the whole XML you are trying to parse.
  That means you do only 1 loop in the `For Each`, then apply `.Item(0)`
  to only keep 1 picture out of it (the first one indeed).
- You can access the `PictureURL` nodes no matter where they are in the XML hierarchy with the XPATH `//PictureXML`
  In XPath, the `//` means any descendant contrary to a single `/`
  which means direct child.
- Even better than `//PictureURL`, you can keep the text **without** the XML by using `//PictureURL/text()`.

Here is the code you should most likely use:

```
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
objXML.LoadXML(objHTTP.ResponseText)

Dim xItemList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set xItemList = objXML.SelectNodes("//PictureURL/text()")

Dim xItem As IXMLDOMNode
For Each xItem In xItemList
    Debug.Print "Image URL"
    Debug.Print xItem.Text
 Next
```

Comment: Perfect this worked great thanks.